# How can I get auditd to report on ONLY the rules I specify with auditctl? (Linux)

Tags: linux, linux-audit

Re-started system, cleared rule list with `auditctl`, but auditd still reports on stuff. Why? How do I add rules to report only on what I want? When I add a rule, other stuff is reported too. Note: I don't want to disable auditing; just reduce it to what I specify.

```
# auditctl -D
# auditctl -l
No rules

# tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1488635581.867:12842): pid=28488 uid=0 auid=26 ses=5324 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_unix acct="postgres" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=USER_END msg=audit(1488635581.868:12843): pid=28488 uid=0 auid=26 ses=5324 msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_loginuid,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd acct="postgres" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
```

Et cetra.

What's going on here? How do I get it to log nothing except for rules I want?

To almost no effect, I tried:

```
-a exclude,always
```

FYI: audit version 2.6.5, kernel: 3.10.0